# Is it proper to separate payments for fees and purchases

Tags: mysql

This are my database tables

fee_table

```
|id|type_id|amount  |due_date  |status|balance|
|1 |1      |200.00  |2013-02-22|paid  |0.00   |
```

fee_payments

```
id |fee_id|amount_paid
|1 |1     |200.00|
```

purchase_table

```
|id|item_id|amount   |due_date  |status|balance|
|1 |1      |3000.00  |2013-01-23|paid  |0.00   |
```

purchase_payments

```
id |purchase_id|amount_paid
 1 |1          |200.00
```

advance_payments

```
id |amount_paid
1  | 500
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: my question if this is a proper structure.. I wanna know  a better database schema than this

Comment: Depends on your use cases. What you want is minimize the querys and also have no duplicated data (which you have, see `status`). Can a purchase have more then one payment? If yes, this is correct for a 1:n correlation. If not -> put it together in a table.

Comment: yes it can have multiple payment because we are accepting partial payment. do you have a better idea  than mine? please help me

Comment: You do not need that much help ;). What I would do is put the purchase balance and fee balance in the purchase table, as you only need them once. Same with status. Rest looks OK to me

Comment: I will remove the fee table? all i need is purchase table, payments, and advance payments?

Comment: No. Just move the balance column

Comment: Ive changed it. Is it ok now?

Comment: do i need to have advance payment  table for each fee and purchase?